# Django form does'nt render even if the code seems alright

Tags: python, html, django

I am beginner to Django. I have just started learning basic forms and here is the code which does'nt work. The method specified for the form in form_page.html is POST, so accordingly in views.py it must render me form_page.html but instead it prints thanks which means it does'nt recognize the method as post and run the else code snippet.Can you help me fix it!!

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from  .forms import formname

def index(request):
    return render(request,'index.html')

def form_name_view(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form=formname(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            print('NAME:',form.cleaned_data['name'])
            print('email:',form.cleaned_data['email'])
            print('text:',form.cleaned_data['text']) 

            
            return render(request,'form_page.html',{'form':form})
            
            
            
    else:
        form=formname()
        return HttpResponse('thanks')
```

**form_page.html**

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang='en'>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title> Basic forms </title>
<head>

<body>

<h1>Fill out the form</h1>
<div class="container">
    <form method="POST">
        {{form.as_p}}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <btn type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Submit</btn>
    </form>
</div>
  

    
</body>
</html>
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.core import validators

class formname(forms.Form):
    name=forms.CharField()
    email=forms.EmailField()
    text=forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from basicformsapp import views
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^formpage/',views.form_name_view,name='form_name_view')
]
```

Comment: The post method would be used when the user actually submits the form. When the user tries to access the page it would be the get method which is used. You must render the form in the get method also.

Comment: Thanks got the concept cleared!

Answer (score 0):

When you first access the view, the method will be `get` not post.
So change your views.py to this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from  .forms import formname

def index(request):
    return render(request,'index.html')

def form_name_view(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST)
        form=formname(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            print('NAME:',form.cleaned_data['name'])
            print('email:',form.cleaned_data['email'])
            print('text:',form.cleaned_data['text']) 

            
            #return render(request,'form_page.html',{'form':form})
            return redirect('home')
            #once the form is valid, you need not render the html again. you can redirect to other page or just render the html. I assumed you saved the data into your db and redirect it to your home screen
            
            
    else:
        form=formname()
        return render(request,'form_page.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: @ SAI SANTOSH CHIRAGThanks I got the concept cleared.But again I do have a question. According to the code provided initially since we try to access the  page the method is 'get' and user is directed to 'form_page.html'  where a form is rendered and once the form is filled and the user clicks on submit button the method becomes 'Post' and then I expect it to go to 'form_name_view' in views.py and print the data which was filled in the form in the Terminal. I don't wish to save it in database. How am I suppose to do it? I tried it as <form  action="formpage/" method="POST"> but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try printing what is coming from the request data i.e, `print(request.POST)`

Comment: I have tried printing `request.POST` Initially it prints GET but later it does'nt print anything. Does that mean it doesnt further switch to views.py. What should I do then?

Comment: Can you post the output when you print `request.POST` . make sure you print after the statement `if request.method == 'POST':`

Comment: I dont get any output for `request.POST`. Output I get when I runserver is  [18/Jan/2021 09:46:17] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 434
[18/Jan/2021 09:46:22] "GET /formpage/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1107

Comment: If you see, you are getting `GET` when you are running the server. Once you go into the form, and submit the data, then you get `POST`. I am asking you print the data after submitting the form. Not after running the server

Comment: Run the server, go to the server, submit the form. Then what is in `request.POST`

Comment: I have edited the code to show where you need to print `requet.POST`

Comment: Well ,Thank you for the guidance I figured out that there isn't error with the django but the html code syntax `<btn type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Submit</btn>` it must be `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Submit</button>` Now the code works fine!`